# Continuation Passing Style (CPS) during graph construction

Tags: haskell, graph, continuations, continuation-passing

I am working on a library for subdivision surfaces. In order to represent the mesh topology I'm using a kind of split-vertex lath data structure (see the diagram on the left side).

[image: Mesh data structure]

During the construction of a mesh, that also can be seen as a graph, it create nodes that should point to another ones that don't exist yet (see diagram on the right side - dashed arrow represent future links). The classical solution is to create a node with an empty pointer and then update it when the other one is created. Since I'm working on Haskell :) and I don't want to go to the dark side of the code (impurity) I'm wondering if it is possible to construct a mesh (graph) without update the data. I guess that CPS (Continuation Passing Style) could do the job but I can't figure out a way.

Is it just a dream?

**UPDATE**

Let me clarify my question a little bit. I am looking for a method to create nodes with direct links (pointers) and by direct link I mean no intermediate tables or maps. Just a plain data definition like that:

```
data Mesh = Edge Vertex Mesh Mesh Vertex | Ground
```

If I'm not wrong and if it is doable, CPS would allow an efficient creation (without node updates) and efficient transverse (without lookups on maps) of a graph. On the other hand the graph would become totally immutable i.e. a single change needs to be propagated through the whole graph e.g. changing the tail of a list.

Am I wrong? If no, how to do it?

Comment: You should be careful of the limitations of your representation.  The principles of Haskell will forbid you from determining the intensional identity of a `Mesh`; i.e. you want to tie the knot, but you will not be able to determine that, if you go somewhere and back, you actually got back instead of somewhere else in an infinite cyclic structure.  In mathematics, graphs are defined over an arbitrary "carrier set" of vertices; I suggest doing the same for pure functional graphs.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is a technique known as [tying the knot](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tying_the_Knot). It exploits lazy evaluation to get the job done. No CPS is necessary.

Suppose you can identify each node by some unique ID (string, integer or whatever). Suppose also that when you create a node, you already know IDs of all the nodes it points to, whether they are already created or not. Then you can use this technique.

You string a `nodes :: Data.Map NodeID Node` through your graph creation functions (use a state monad for extra convenience). When you create a node, you add it to the map. When you create an edge that should point to node  named `x`, you use  a `fromMaybe $ lookup nodes x`. *It does not matter whether a node named x is already created, or will be created in the future*. As long as it *is* created at some point, you are set. It will only be fetched from the map when you need it.

This is how I used to create a graph from its textual description. Perhaps there are other, better ways.

If, when creating a node, you don't know IDs of all the nodes that your node will point to, you need to modify this technique a bit, e.g. pass around a map from node ID to a list of its neighbours, and build each list incrementally.

You should be careful and avoid evaluating the lazy values before you finish building the graph.

Comment: This will not work, as when you insert a note, that creates a new map, so you may be referring to a version of the map in which the node will never exist. Instead, construct the map all at once using `fromList` or similar. That way, you can easily reference the final map to tie the knot. EDIT: Actually, you can still do it this way, just make sure that the map used in the lookups is the _final_ map, not the current one.

Comment: @hammar: yes, a good point. I forgot that I actually have run into this problem. I ended up using the final map in the lookups.

Comment: "used to" create a graph?  How do you do it now?

Comment: This would be a nice solution in case of uniform mesh, where the label prediction would be straightforward. As you said, for a general case some work around should done get it right. My question here is more about the possible use of CPS (see the UPDATE on my question). If CPS doesn't work then I will go for your propose. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not using CPS... but I'm working on a planar graph library for Haskell, using a similar scheme to what you've described above.  Edges are added by specifying which existing edge comes before or after it.

The actual graph implementation is done, what's left is to get the binary serialisation working and performant (using PLANAR_CODE for starters, maybe Graph6 and Sparse6 as well) and a few other extra things.

Currently you get the dual graph (which seems to be what you've also drawn in) with a separate function, though I am considering having the dual calculated each time you add an edge (assuming a connected graph).

The code can be obtained from `darcs get http://code.haskell.org/~ivanm/planar-graph/`; a sample usage (which is what I'm developing this library for) is at `http://code.haskell.org/~ivanm/dangd/`.

---

*Taken from the Haddock documentation as an example of using it:*

For example, let `g` refer to the following graph (where
`n1`, etc. are both the labels and the variable names):

```
     ====                    ====
    ( n1 )                  ( n2 )
     ====                    ====





                             ====
                            ( n3 )
                             ====
```

We can add an edge between `n1` and `n2` (using **Anywhere** as the
**EdgePos** since there are currently no edges on either node):

```
 ((e1,e2),g') = addEdge n1 Anywhere n2 Anywhere "e1" "e2" g
```

This will result in the following graph:

```
                  e2
     ====  <---------------  ====
    ( n1 )                  ( n2 )
     ====  --------------->  ====
                  e1




                             ====
                            ( n3 )
                             ====
```

If we want to add edges between `n2` and `n3`, we have three
options for the location on `n2`:

- Use `Anywhere`: since there is only one other edge, it makes no
  difference in terms of the embedding where the second edge goes.
- Put the new edge `BeforeEdge e2` (going clockwise around `n2`).
- Put the new edge `AfterEdge e2` (going clockwise around `n2`).

Since `n2` currently only has one edge, all three **EdgePos** values
will result in the same graph, so we can arbitrarily pick one:

```
 ((e3,e4),g'') = addEdge n2 (BeforeEdge e2) n3 Anywhere "e3" "e4" g'
```

However, with more edges care must be taken on which **EdgePos**
value is used.  The resulting graph is:

```
                  e2
     ====  <---------------  ====
    ( n1 )                  ( n2 )
     ====  --------------->  ====
                  e1         |  ^
                             |  |
                          e3 |  | e4
                             |  |
                             v  |
                             ====
                            ( n3 )
                             ====
```

The same graph (up to the actual **Edge** values; so it won't satisfy
`==`) would have been obtained with:

```
 ((e4,e3), g'') = addEdge n3 Anywhere n2 (BeforeEdge e2) "e4" "e3" g'
```

Comment: I've been looking into your code and you are using map's insertion and lookup functions to construct the graph. My idea using CPS is to avoid any map's lookup or update. See the UPDATE in my question. Thanks

Comment: @LambdaStaal: I was just presenting this as an alternative :)  Though can I ask *why* you are so against lookups or updates on underlying Maps?

Comment: Please don't get me wrong. I'm not _against_ them! Moreover I'll use them. Even if CPS works here, it seems a too complex idea to keep it on production code. I'm just wondering if it would be possible to create a graph without update or underlying tables. I imagine that it would be more efficient and, even more bizarre, I fell that it is more natural solution. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @LambdaStaal: OK, I thought you had some particular reason for wanting to implement graphs here without them, rather than just wondering if it could be done.  I suppose in my use case I *need* to be able to update/alter a graph, which I assume would be the general case (as opposed to a static graph).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't need to store the link to the NextA and NextB edge inside a Edge. As these are something that can be calculated by traversing from the current Edge why not write a function that take a Edge and return its NextA / NextB edge which are as par the diagram based of clockwise direction of Edge's A and B part.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get it. Are you saying to calculate NextA/B and then store it on a table/map and use it for future searches. Could you clarify your answer?  For me NextA or NextB are part of the transversing process it.